# Need assistance for creating a simple bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, sh

I've created this bash file putting on it a secuence of commands i often run for synching files from my digital camera. the point is it doesn't to ANYTHING! What am i missing?
thank you!
code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#temporal
mkdir /tmp/canon

#copy files from camera
rsync -r /run/user/mango/gvfs/g*/DCIM /tmp/canon
cd /tmp/canon

#get files from subdirs
find ./ -name '*.JPG' -exec mv '{}' ./ \;

#remove dirs
ls -l | awk -F'[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' '/^d/{print $NF}'| xargs -i rm -rf '{}' \;

#recreate folder structure with year|month pattern
jhead -n%Y/%m/%f *.JPG

#Sync with external HD
rsync -r --ignore-existing . /media/mango/WD/FOTOS/
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Try to add `-v` to rsync and see if it does do something or not. After that check the other commands. Make sure also that your filenames end in `.JPG` and not also `.jpg`. You could use `-iname` to ignore the case.

Comment: Do you need to make it executable? That is, "chmod u+x script.sh"

Comment: Also add `-v` to both your `mv` and `rm` commands.

Comment: Do not parse ls output. Use this instead ``for curFile in *; do [[ -d "$curFile" ]] && [[ curFile =~ ^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$ ]] && rm -rf "$curFile"; done``

Comment: thank you for all the tips, making it verbose just showed me the mistake. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it does not even do the mkdir, then it sound most likely that the version of the script you want is not the one running.  Try using an qualified path, such as `./myscript` or an absolute path, like `/home/joe/bin/myscript`.  The command `type myscript` will tell from where the shell is running it.

Also, try running the script after adding `set -x` to the top of the script or using `bash -x myscript`; that will show every line as it is executed.

If this still doesn't help, there could be bash startup code, such as in `.bashrc` getting in the way.  That's much harder to diagnose, although the same `set -x` can be used, although with great caution unless a second user can login and edit this user's startup scripts since mistakes in startup scripts can make it impossible to login to the system.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
chmod +x yourscriptname

 ./yourscriptname
```

Make usre you are running the same script you made.